# Effective grails plugin development

Tags: grails, plugins, maven, intellij-idea

This has been very upsetting for me up till now. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. IDE I'm using is Intellij IDEA.
2. Building a grails application.
3. Grails application specifies two dependencies on in house grails plugins also being developed in IntelliJ as separate grails plugin projects.

Now to make any changes to plugins, I update the source code in plugin projects and use mavan-install (Maven Publisher plugin) to deploy to local Maven repository.
I have to uninstall the plugin in core grails project. Delete the plugin cache from ivy and then run the core grails project which gets the latest copy of plugin from local maven repository.

What's the effective and ideal way to achieve this? A single change makes me do some 5 minutes of labour work to even test and run core application.

Any recommendations/ best practices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use inline plugins for this - see section "Specifying Plugin Locations" in http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins

By specifying the plugin project directory with `grails.plugin.location.<plugin-name>` as the location of the installed plugin, you can edit the real files and the changes will affect the test application, and there's no need to sync anything up.

Comment: I have a question somewhat related to this.  I'm using this method (i.e. having the location of the plugin in my BuildConfig.groovy) and it works great.  My problem is how to manage this plugin when I deploy to a cloud provider where it can't automatically install the plugin since the plugin isn't available via the Grails Plugin Portal.  What is the best or preferred method of handling this situation?  I've opened an SO question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905350/how-to-deploy-grails-app-with-private-plugin-to-cloud

Comment: Does the install hook execute, I have a plugin that needs to copy some file resources and it doesn't appear to happen when I specify the location in `BuildConfig`