# How to deploy grails app with private plugin to cloud

Tags: grails

I've created a private plugin for domain objects that are shared between two grails applications.  I'm able to use the plugin successfully in my local environment as I've set the path to it via the BuildConfig file.  For example, I have the following directories:

```
appOne/
myPlugin/grails-my-plugin-0.1.zip     (myPlugin is a grails plugin project dir)
```

In: **appOne/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy:**

```
grails.plugin.location.compileMyPlugin = "../myPlugin"
```

My question is, what is the proper/best way to handle "packaging" this plugin with my app release so I can deploy it to a cloud service where it won't be available for download?  I imagine there is a way to have grails do this for you but I'm unsure.  (I'm very new to grails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following to resolve this in Grails 2.1.0:

1) In the Grails Plugin Project:
`grails package-plugin`     Produces the grails-myplugin-0.1.zip file

2) Copy plugin to my application's lib directory   (appOne/lib/grails-myplugin-0.1.zip)

3) In BuildConfig.groovy

- **Remove:** grails.plugin.location.compilemyPlugin = "../myPlugin"
  This was/is used during development to prevent the rebuild-reinstall process
  when updating files included in the plugin.
- **Add:**

  plugins {
  .....
   compile ':grails-myPlugin:0.1'  
  }

4) Test by cleaning appOne and re-run which will install/re-install the plugin via the lib directory

5) Commit all changes and add the plugin zip file to appOne and push.  The cloud provider,
Heroku in this case, can then resolve the dependency.

Comment: This is interesting...so you are saying that Grails will resolve the plugin via your application's lib directory?

Comment: Yes.  It will find the plugin in the lib directory and will install it.

Comment: Wow. Seems like you stumbled across an undocumented feature :)

Answer (score 2):

When you create you .war file for deployment, grails simply includes your plugin. So you have nothing special to do.

If your project is build in the cloud, you might try to specify a file path as local repository:

```
repositories {
  grailsCentral()
  localRepo "../myPlugin"
}
```

Just drop your zipped plugin in this folder and grails will find it.

Comment: I use Heroku, and I can't deploy a war file directly.  You push your project, and Heroku builds the file using your/its dependency mgmt tools.  Since my plugin isn't public (and I'm not running an internet accessible repository) when Heroku goes to build my project, it has no way to resolve the plugin dependency.

Comment: see my update. You should give a try on you local machine to see where Grails searches for plugins. It could be that you have to rename your zip-file

Comment: +1 - localRepo doesn't appear to be valid.  Even though this didn't work, I appreciate your help and it did get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: repositories { flatDir name:'localPlugins', dirs:'./deploy-plugins'} - worked for me if zip files moved into root/deploy-plugins and the prefix 'grails-' is removed from the .zip files

Answer (score 1):

Your build script should first package the plugin, then install the plugin into your Grails application.  At least, that is how I have to do it.  If you try and have both your plugin specified in the BuildConfig dependencies and as an inline plugin, Grails tends to complain about that.